# What file should i add this code to enable CORS in node js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

I am trying to enable CORS in my node js server. but I don't know to what file should I append the code above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: file? append? seems like you have `cors` module ... is there an error with your code?

Comment: I guess you mean where you should add that actual snippet? Wherever your application code is—`app.js` or whatever name you gave it. Whatever file you call `node` on to run your app—`node app.js`, `node whatever-your-filename-is.js`

Comment: in the file which you have `var express = require('express')` I dont think you have a node project without `express`

Comment: Thanks guys. I am installing express

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.corsOrigin("http://localhost:8000"); // to particular url
```

or

```
app.corsOrigin("*");    //allow cors origin for all request url
```

or you can try [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)